# Pass data from Detail View Controller to another table View

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have two table view controllers where the data comes from an endpoint. In detail view of the table view 1 i would like to pass the object that was selected to the table view 2 tried to use prepare for segue but unsuccessful. Here is my code

First Table View

```
class ListContentsViewController: BaseMainList {


    lazy var concreteFetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = { [unowned self] in
        let occurredAtSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "occuredAt", ascending: false)
        let identifierSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "identifier", ascending: false)

        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Contents")
        request.sortDescriptors = [occurredAtSort, identifierSort]


        let fetch = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext(),
                                               sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetch.delegate = self
        do {
            try fetch.performFetch()
        } catch _ {
        }

        return fetch
        }()

    override var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
        get {
            return concreteFetchedResultsController
        }
        set {
            self.fetchedResultsController = newValue
        }


    }

       var selectedContents: Selected?

    // MARK: - View Life Cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()





    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    }






    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let segueId = segue.identifier {
            switch segueId {
            case "ContentDetailsSegue":
                if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell, indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
                    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

                    let object = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Selected
                    let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! ContentsDetailsViewController
                    controller. selectedContents = object

                }

                    default:
                    ()
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Content Detail View Controller

```
  var selectedContents: Selected?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = true



        mapView.delegate = self

        loadContents()

    }


    // MARK: - Load 

    func load() {

   if let content = selectedContents {
            labelt.text = content.name

          labely.text = content.email

           labelu.text = content.number


}

  @IBAction func ignore(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        if let content = self. selectedContents {

            ContentServices.ignoreWithID(andContentID: content.identifier, withCompletion: { (error) in


                let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("Success", comment: ""), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


                self.ignoreBt.enabled = false


                return
            })

        }

    }
```

After tap button is expected that it passes the object that was selected in table view 1 to table view 2. How can i proceed?

Comment: Does it go inside case "ContentDetailsSegue"?

Comment: @Luzo yes  table view 1 pass data to Content Details View Controller after this i need pass data to table view 2 inside of ContentDetails class

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to know how to know when the data are present. Create a function with passing attribute in Content Details VC, it will contain only setting the property to the VC and calling tableview reload. Then you can assign data in your TBview delegate